# How to solve these types of ODEs?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

This question is motivated by the following differential equation: $$\frac{d\sigma}{ds} = h - \frac{f'(t)}{f(t)}\sin \sigma.$$Here $h$ is constant, $f$ only depends of $t$ and $\sigma = \sigma(s)$. My issue is that $\sin \sigma = \sin(\sigma (s))$ and if one wanted to integrate this we obtain $$\int_0^s\sin \sigma(t)dt.$$However I don't know how to solve such an integral (is it even possible?). In a general setting, I wonder if there's already a method to solve ODEs of the type $$\dot{x} = \cos(x), \ \ \ \text{ or } \ \ \ \dot{x} = \sin(x).$$

Thank you very much!

`Edit:` Let me simplify even further by making this into $\frac{d\sigma}{ds} = h(1-\sin \sigma)$. In this case we get: $$\frac{d\sigma}{ds} = h(1-\sin \sigma).$$I stress that $\sin \sigma$ really is $\sin(\sigma(s))$, so I can't use separation of variables. If anyone has an idea to proceed I appreciate.

Comment: Is $\frac{f'(t)}{f(t)}$ effectively a constant as it does not depend on $s$ or $\sigma$? In that case using t in the integral is confusing. Whether the integral of the $sin$ is easy or not depends on what $\sigma (s)$ is.

Comment: @Paul It is just a dummy variable. You can think of it as $\tau$ if you wish. In this situation, $\sigma(s)$ is a function that measures the angle between two vectors in some tangent space. If you have some reference for this type of problems I would appreciate you could share. Thank you

Comment: Why can't you use separation of variables? Integrating gives $$\int \frac{d\sigma}{1 - \sin \sigma} = \int h \,ds .$$ In fact in this case we can even solve for $\sigma$ as an explicit function of $s$.

Comment: N.b. $\sigma'(s) = h - A \sin \sigma$ is a little more difficult to integrate when $A \not\in \{0, \pm h\}$, but one can still find explicit solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separation of variables is a fine method here. Denote $\tau := \frac{f'(t)}{f(t)}$ as suggested in the comments, so that our equation is
$$\frac{d\sigma}{ds} = h - \tau \sin \sigma .$$
Notice first that there are constant solutions $\sigma = \sigma_0$, $\sin \sigma_0 = \frac{h}\tau$; these exist precisely when $|h| \leq |\tau|$. In particular, the behavior of the special case $\tau = h$ considered in the edit is qualitatively different from other values of $\tau$.

Separating and integrating gives
$$\int \frac{d\sigma}{h - \tau \sin \sigma} = \int ds.$$
To evaluate the integral on the left-hand side we can use the tangent half-angle substitution, $\sigma = 2 \arctan u$, which rationalizes the integral,
$$2\int \frac{du}{h u^2 - 2 \tau u + h},$$ leaving it amenable to standard techniques.

At this point the expression—and the qualitative behavior of the system—depends on the sign of the discriminant $\Delta := 4(\tau^2 - h^2)$ of the denominator.

- If $\Delta < 0$ (i.e., $|h| > |\tau|$), we get
  $$\frac{2}{\sqrt{h^2 - \tau^2}} \arctan \left(\frac{h \tan \frac{\sigma}{2} - \tau}{\sqrt{h^2 - \tau^2}}\right) = s + C .$$
  Rearranging gives that near generic points the solutions are given by
  $$\sigma(s) = 2 \arctan \left(\frac{\sqrt{h^2 - \tau^2} \tan \left[\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{h^2 - \tau^2} (s + C)\right]}{h}\right) + 2 \pi k, \quad k \in \Bbb Z .$$
- If $\Delta = 0$, so that $\tau = \pm h$, the integral in $u$ is $\frac{2}{h} \int \frac{du}{(u \mp 1)^2}$. (We assume $h \neq 0$; that case is anyway trivial.) Notice that in this case there are also constant solutions, $\sigma = \pi (2 k \pm \frac12)$, $k \in \Bbb Z$.
  (Notice that in this case the original integral can be handled with a simpler method:
  \begin{multline}\frac{1}{h}\int\frac{d\sigma}{1 \mp \sin \sigma} = \frac{1}{h} \int\frac{(1 \pm \sin \sigma) \,d\sigma}{(1 \mp \sin \sigma)(1 \pm \sin \sigma)} \\ = \frac{1}{h} \int \frac{(1 \pm \sin \sigma)\,d\sigma}{\cos^2 \sigma} = \frac{1}{h} \int \left(\sec^2 \sigma \pm \sec \sigma \tan \sigma \right) d\sigma = \tan \sigma + \sec \sigma + C.)\end{multline}
- The case $\Delta > 0$ ($|h| < |\tau|$) is similar to the case $\Delta < 0$, except that (1) an explicit solution involves hyperbolic rather than trigonometric functions, and (2) as mentioned at the beginning there are some constant solutions.

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 3):

As it was mentioned in the comments, there is no obstacle to using the separation of variables. Appart from constant solutions $\sigma \equiv \frac{\pi}{2} + 2 k\pi$, the solutions of the equation are given implicitly by
$$
\frac{2 \sin(\sigma/2)}{\cos(\sigma/2)-\sin(\sigma/2)} = h s + K.
$$

Below you can find a Stream plot (with $h=1$).

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot!